# php mysql assign the next sequence number to the row

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am using mysql with PHP. I have a students table like this. I am using InnoDB engine.

```
id    int  AUTO_INCREMENT
regno int
name varchar
```

whenever a new student is inserted, I want to assign the next available regno. for example the regno of previous student is 1 then the value should be 2 for the next entry. The auto increment does not work here as it may create gaps. (I am using transactions, so after inserting a row to students table, there are few more queries that may cause rollback, in which case, the auto increment id is incremented although no actual record is inserted). Also, I don't care if there is a gap present between old regnos... e.g regno may have 1,2,3,5,10,11,12 in sequence. now when next student is inserted I would like 12+1=13 for the this student. Also, I want to make sure the regno is not duplicated. (Although regno has a UNIQUE index, but I don't want to throw error. It should get the next number).

I've two solutions in mind. 
1: (pseudo-code)
   a. Query Database for the newregno = max(regno)+1
   b. assign newregno to student while inserting the row.

In this case I am just concerned about that 2 instances of application may query the database at the same time and get the same newregno causing the duplicate.

2: Use triggers... Update the regno after real row insertion. (I've not read much about the triggers, but if any one suggest this is a better approach, I'll go for it)

Any suggestion?

EDIT--- 
The regno (registeration number) may not be unique itself in future but will be unique along with some other columns e.g. course/session. So please don't offer me an 'auto increment' index type solution.

Comment: You can use auto increment in database for regno .

Comment: @DevangRathod  Please read the question in complete... I've already told auto increment will not work here.

Comment: Is there a purpose of having two columns that i'm guessing to be 'unique'

Comment: maybe like this: `INSERT INTO table SET regno  = ( SELECT MAX(regno) + 1 FROM table);`

Comment: Its morning here, but for me REGNO stands for registration number, you can get it from auto-incremented ID or if u wanna actual count of students, count rows :]

Comment: @class regno may become a part of another key in future and will no more be unique itself but will be unique in a course/session.

Comment: @Imperative .. Is this valid ?? I am getting the error on  this query .. INSERT INTO students SET regno = ( SELECT MAX(regno) + 1 FROM students );... that says #1093 - You can't specify target table 'students' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/

Increment uses different algorithms for calculating the id. You need to set it to avoid holes.

Comment: more detailed look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: @priyolahiri... That was a great article and I am going to use it in my future development but in current scenario, I am not going to use auto increment (Please review my Edits). I think triggers may be a good solution in my case.

Comment: or as part of your transaction you can do SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name; and then assign to a variable and increment when doing the new insert/update?